# How do I strip email tags <>

Tags: php

I have this email  `First Last <email@email.com>`  How do I strip everything and just get `email@email.com` returned? -using php

Comment: Look into `filter_var` and the sanitize filters. You can also easily validate emails as well using `filter_var` [Sanitize Filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)

Comment: http://txt2re.com/ is a great resource for this type of thing if you're new to regexes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) under`Regular Expressions`

```
<?php
$str='First Last <email@email.com>';
preg_match_all('/<(.*?)>/', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1][0];
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
   email@email.com
```

[image]

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/104026)

Comment: Perfect.. thanks, i guess its time to learn regex :/

Answer (score 0):

```
$email = 'First Last <email@email.com>';
$email = preg_replace('/^.*<(.*?)>$/', '\1', $email);
```

Comment: Please also comment the code, even if minimal, to be more educative.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you,

```
<?php
   $string = "First Last <email@email.com>";
   $pattern = '/([a-z0-9])(([-a-z0-9._])*([a-z0-9]))*\@([a-z0-9])' .
'(([a-z0-9-])*([a-z0-9]))+' . '(\.([a-z0-9])([-a-z0-9_-])?([a-z0-9])+)/i';
   preg_match ($pattern, $string, $matches);
   echo $matches[0];
?>
```